# condition problem while checking errors in log file in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to check error with count2 which code in below

```
DAY=`TZ=GMT-3 date "+%Y-%m-%d %H"`

count2=$(cat $source_dir/xx.log |grep $check_str|grep "$DAY" | wc -l)

if [[ 3 -gt $count2 ]]
then
echo "$count2"
else
echo "works"
```

when i work it in sh -x mode the output is;

```
++ grep '2019-10-26 04'
++ wc -l
+ count2=385
+ [[ 3 -gt 385 ]]
+ echo works
```

why the condition enters else? altought 3 does not gt 385 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ 3 -gt $count2 ]] # with count2 being 385
then
echo "$count2"
else
echo "works"
```

> Why does the condition enters else although 3 is not greater than 385 (reworded to hopefully make clearer)?.

It enters the `else` precisely *because* 3 is not greater than 385. Your condition checks if `3 > 385`, executes the `then` bit if it does, or executs the `else` bit if it doesn't. This is as expected (from the code anyway, even if it's not what *you* expected).

---

*Perhaps* you meant to put the condition in the opposite sense, it's hard to tell from your question. If that *is* the case, it would be `$count2 -gt 3`.